# Is there an easy way to disable logging in an osgi environment?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, apache-httpcomponents

Is there an easy way to disable logging in an osgi environment?

I get a lot of:

```
[java] org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient[org.apache.http.wire] : <<
"        <form action="" id="httpsForm" class="hide"
target="httpsIframe" enctype="multipart/form-data"
method="post"></form>[\n]"
     [java] org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient[org.apache.http.wire] :
<< "    </div>[\n]"
     [java] org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient[org.apache.http.wire] :
<< "[\n]"
     [java] org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient[org.apache.http.wire] :
<< "        [\n]"
     [java] org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient[org.apache.http.wire] :
<< "    [\n]"
     [java] org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient[org.apache.http.wire] :
<< "    [\n]"
```

I use the pax osgi bundle for logging, which enables many logging
facilities.

Is there a simple way to disable logging in httpclient? maybe in code?

I tried:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
and
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
```

but that doesnt fix it, same behavior

please tell me a fix

thanks